# Junit tests wont run using ant

Tags: java, ant, junit

I have been able to successfully compile and run this project using ant. But when i try to run my test files, it gives me a strange  Reference ./lib/junit-4.11.jar not found. I probably am doing something wrong in the refid that i have to mention in the junit task. Please point out the mistake.

```
<target name="clean">
    <delete dir="build"/>
</target>

<target name="compile">
    <mkdir dir="build/classes"/>
    <javac srcdir="./src/com/twu/biblioteca/" destdir="build/classes"/>
</target>

<target name="jar">
    <mkdir dir="build/jar"/>
    <jar destfile="build/jar/Application.jar" basedir="build/classes">
        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Main-Class" value="com.twu.biblioteca.Application"/>
        </manifest>
    </jar>
</target>

<target name="run">
    <java jar="build/jar/Application.jar" fork="true"/>
</target>

<target name="junit" depends="compile">

    <junit printsummary="yes" haltonfailure="no">

        <!-- Project classpath, must include junit.jar -->
        <classpath refid="./lib/junit-4.11.jar" />

        <!-- test class -->
        <classpath location="./test/BooksController" />

        <test name="com.twu.biblioteca.BooksControllerTest"
              haltonfailure="no" todir="./report">
            <formatter type="plain" />
            <formatter type="xml" />
        </test>

    </junit>
</target>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your junit *classpath* elements.  The *refid* attribute allows you to refer to a predefined reference and ant is notifying you that there is no such reference.  Additionally, you should have only one *classpath* element under the junit task (it may work with more than one, but the documentation supports only one).

Remove those *classpath* elements and replace them with

```
<classpath>
    <pathelement location="lib/junit-4.11.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="test/BooksController"/>
</classpath>
```

and it should work.  Here we build up the classpath by adding the junit jar to the path and then the directory containing your tests.  You will probably have to add your main classes to this as well, with another *pathelement* giving their location.

See [the ant documentation](https://ant.apache.org/manual/using.html#path) for more on these *path-like structures*.